# How do I select rows from one table that do not exist in another table with a specific value

Tags: t-sql

I know this sounds simple and I have found many similar examples but I can't make sense of it to match my specific problem.

I have tried some nested selects and some left joins but they didn't work.

I have a Building table and a ComplianceItems Table 
A Building can have many ComplianceItems.
I also have a ComplianceItemType table that contains all the possible types.

I want to find all the Buildings that don't have a ComplianceItem of Type 17 or 18.
I see lots of examples that select the parent record when there are no child records.
But I want to select all the parent records that don't have a Compliance Item of type 17 or 18

How can I add this condition to my query?

```
select OC.lOwnersCorporationID
From Strata.dbo.OwnersCorporation OC
Left Join ComplianceDEMO.dbo.ComplianceItem CI on OC.lOwnersCorporationID = CI.OwnersCorporationID
Where CI.OwnersCorporationID IS NULL
AND OC.bManaged = 'Y'
```

BTW I don't care about performance as this query will only be run once and used as part of an insert statement to create missing records.

## UPDATE

Obviously my data is more complex than this but this should give you an idea.

```
Table Definition
  Ownerscorporation Table
    OwnersCorporationID    INT   PK
    PlanNumber             Varchar(10)

  ComplianceItem Table
    ComplianceItemID      INT    PK
    ComplianceTypeID      INT    FK
    OwnersCorporationID   INT    FK

  ComplianceType Table
    ComplianceTypeID      INT    PK
    Name                  varchar(50)

Test Data
Owners Corporation Table
ID        PlanNumber
===============================================
1         1001
2         1002
3         1003


Compliance Item Table
ComplianceItemID     ComplianceTypeID    OwnersCorporationID
==================================================================
1                    1                   1           
2                    2                   1
3                    3                   1
4                    4                   1
5                    5                   1
6                    1                   2
7                    2                   2
8                    4                   2
9                    1                   3
10                   2                   3
11                   3                   3


Compliance Type Table
==================================================================
ComplianceTypeID     Name
1                    Asbestos Report
2                    Capital Works Fund
3                    Anchor Point Compliance
4                    Window Lock Compliance
5                    Pool Compliance



The Problem
=========================
Probably easier in two parts.
Find all the OwnersCorporations That Don't have a Compliance type of 4
Find all the OwnersCorporations That Don't have a Compliance type of 5

Expected Results
=========================
Part 1
OwnersCorporationID
3

Part 2
OwnersCorporationID
2
3
```

## UPDATE 2

It looks like Matt's answer in the comments worked on the test data.

```
Select OwnersCorporationID
From OwnersCorporationTable
Where OwnersCorporationID Not In
(
    Select OwnersCorporationID 
    From ComplianceItemTable
    Where (ComplianceTypeID =5 )
```

Returned 2 and 3

And

```
Select OwnersCorporationID
From OwnersCorporationTable
Where OwnersCorporationID Not In
(
    Select OwnersCorporationID 
    From ComplianceItemTable
    Where (ComplianceTypeID =4 )
```

Returned 3
I will need to run it in two parts when I use it to create the missing records.
I'll try and convert it to run on my real data.  Hopefully I haven't simplified it too much :)
Thanks for your help Matt.  If you would like the points please post this as an answer.

Comment: [`not exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) may be of use.

Comment: Could you provide the sample data and the output expected, my friend?

Comment: If I understand correctly ComplianceItems has a type and a building_id of some sort?

Could you: select fields from buildings where building id not in(select building_id from complianceItem where type = 17 or type = 18 )

Comment: Or: select fields from buildings b where not exists (select 1 from complianceItems where buildingId = b.buildingId and (type in (17,18)))

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for this

```
SELECT OC.lOwnersCorporationID
From Strata.dbo.OwnersCorporation OC
INNER JOIN ComplianceDEMO.dbo.ComplianceItem CI on OC.lOwnersCorporationID = CI.OwnersCorporationID AND 
CI.ComplianceTypeID NOT IN (17,18) AND
OC.bManaged = 'Y'
```

Comment: Hi Jaydip,  Your query returned no results and no errors.  Should the be a "Where" in their somewhere?  I have not seen all those AND's on a Join before but that could just be me :)

Comment: Hi, I have modified the query and remove the NULL check. try now

Comment: Hi Jaydip, Great effort but it returned everything multiple times.  Never mind, Mat's comment above put me on the right track and solved it.  Creating boring test data also made it easier to think about.  Thanks for your effort.